# Construction "DID SEE" in literature

Tags: grammar, literature

From Isaac Asimov (Little Lost Robot)

> WHEN I **DID SEE** SUSAN CALVIN AGAIN, IT WAS AT the door of her office

Is this a grammatic error? Past simple - WHEN I **SAW** SUSAN

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is this a grammatic error?

No, it isn't. You need to read this in context:

> It was two days before I could get to see her again.
>
> WHEN I DID SEE SUSAN CALVIN AGAIN, IT WAS AT the door of her office.
>   Files were being moved out.

The narrator did *not* see her for two days. Now he describes what happened when he (finally) *did* see her again.

Comment: This (1) is answering a question already flagged as a duplicate, (2) does not even mention emphatic _do_, and (3) gives no supporting evidence, just coming across as personal opinion about correctness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Answering a question already marked as duplicate is not possible. What you should really ask yourself is whether the answer helped the person asking for help. I am under the impression you forgot what this is all about, before anything else.

Comment: I'm sorry, michael.hor257k, but accepting your opinion would lead to the question someone once asked here about the best way to keep goldfish being on-topic. I said **flagged** (ie pointed out) as a duplicate. As Janus Bahs Jacquet has said: '[Y]ou  should always keep in mind the possibility of duplicates when reading (and answering) a question, and consider how likely a question is to be a duplicate. This one … [pretty] likely.' If the same questions keep being allowed and answered, the site degenerates into an inconsistent hotch-potch.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As it happens, I wrote my answer before you flagged the question as a duplicate. Not that it matters much, because I don't think the other question provides an answer to this one - and I don't see why your opinion on this matter should take precedence over mine.